# Scala check value inside mapping

Tags: scala, dictionary, recurrence

Allright so i don't know if this is possible, but let's say we have the following list:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 1)
```

If i want to apply a map over this, is there a way for me to check if i've already had a value before, e.g. on the 4th value (the 2nd 1) it'll say that it already came across the 1 and then throw an error or something.

Comment: I'm assuming there's some reason why you don't want to simply test the `List` for uniqueness before mapping.

Comment: Why not use a `Set[A]` which guarantees uniqueness of elements in the collection?

Comment: @jwvh Actually there is not, this would indeed be a faster solution

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Because the list is generated, and not by input, and thus double values can appear, which should throw an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be the role of a `foldLeft` stage:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 1).foldLeft(List[Int]()) {
  // The item has already been encountered:
  case (uniqueItems, b) if uniqueItems.contains(b) => {
    // If as stated, you want to throw an exception, that's where you could do it
    uniqueItems
  }
  // New item not seen yet:
  case (uniqueItems, b) => uniqueItems :+ b
}
```

foldLeft traverses a sequence while working (at each new element), with a result based on the previous ones.

For each element, the pattern matching `(uniqueItems, b)` should be understood this way: `uniqueItems` is the "accumulator" (it's initialized as `List[Int]()`) and will be updated (or not) for each item of the list. And `b` if the new item of the list which is currently being processed.

By the way, this example is a (non-efficient) `distinct` over a list.

Comment: Allright, thanks for this answer.

Would this also work on e.g. Persons with name and age:

List(Person("Frank", 30), Person("Eva", 24), Person("Frank", 23)...)

And then throw an error if we come across the same name twice?

Comment: Yes, foldLeft applies on a sequence of any type. `List(Person("Frank", 30), Person("Eva", 24), Person("Frank", 23)...).foldLeft(List[Person]()) { case (uniqueItems, person) if uniqueItems.contains(person) => throw SomeException; case (uniqueItems, person) => uniqueItems :+ person }`

Comment: And this works on just checking the names, so Person("Frank", 30) and Person("Frank", 23) are considered equal

Comment: My previous comment was concidering case classes where two elements were equal if both the name and the age are the same. If you want to consider only the name, then the first case could be: `case (uniqueItems, Person(name, age)) if uniqueItems.exists(_.name == name) => throw SomeException`. But we're drifting a bit from the original question.

Answer (score 2):

```
List(1, 2, 3, 1).distinct.map (n => n*n) 
// res163: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 9)
```

This code removes duplicates, then performs the mappings in a self documenting, brief manner.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ: Much thanks for that text template. Do you really think an explanation is needed? Can you be more precise? What didn't you understand? Let me guess - it was the review queue, making that suggestion.

Comment: Wouldn't have made it into the review queue at all if it had an explanation: I mean, just look at the other answers. They clarify what the code does, and expand into how exactly the code works. Your code snippet, while it may work/be shorter, is a far cry away from a *good* answer.

Comment: Yes, because their code is overly complicated. You don't have any scala-reputation, so maybe you should not review such simple one-liners but stick to languages of expertise. There is a *filter* button/link on the review page, where you can reduce the noise of alien tags.

Answer (score 1):

`fold` is probably the way to go. The problem is that each iteration has to carry both the memory of previous elements as well as the `map()` results as it is being built.

```
List(1, 2, 3, 11).foldRight((Set[Int](),List[String]())) {case (i, (st, lst)) =>
  if (st(i)) throw new Error        //duplicate encountered
  else (st + i, i.toString :: lst)  //add to memory and map result
}._2                                //pull the map result from the tuple
```